# Given a drawing of an ellipse is there any geometric construction we can do to find it's foci?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

For example if we're given a drawing of a circle, we can take three different points on it, draw the perpendicular bisectors of them and the intersection point is the center. Is it possible to find the foci of an ellipse in a similar way?

Comment: Are we given the the entire ellipse or part of it?

Comment: the entire ellipse. I'm not sure if it works but I think one can find the ellipse center by drawing a retangle on it and the center of the retangle is the center of the ellipse . You get it ?

Comment: forget the retangle idea

Comment: What operations are allowed? I take it you are talking about compass and ruler constructions, but how can you access the ellipse in that? Can you use arbitrary points on the ellipse? Can you draw tangents to the ellipse?

Comment: This is probably not what you want: In complex projective geometry there is a simple construction. Start with the two ideal circle points $[1:\pm i:0]$ and construct tangents from these to the ellipse. These four tangents will intersect in six points: the two ideal points you started with, a pair of complex conjugate points (which would be the foci if your conic were a hyperbola instead of an ellipse) and the two real foci you are after. Of course, although the vocabulary used here is very geometric, a construction involving points with complex coordinates is ill suited for ruler and compass.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take two parallel lines $l_1,l_2$ cutting the ellipse in $A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2$. Let $C_i$ be the midpoint of $A_i B_i$: the center of the ellipse lies on the $C_1 C_2$ line. Once the center $O$ of the ellipse is found, take a circle with center $O$ cutting the ellipse in the vertices of a rectangle: the symmetry axis of the rectangle are the axis of the ellipse too, hence the vertices of the ellipse are found. Given the center and the vertices, to find the foci of an ellipse is an easy task:

[image]

Comment: I just wanna see the proof that the center lies on that line $C_i$ but that was awesome, thank you

Comment: Please label the points/lines, I can't tell what's going on in the picture.

Comment: @onlyme: An ellipse is the image of a circle under an affine transformation. Such transformations preserve collinear ratios (in particular, midpoints go to midpoints) as well as incidence and parallelism. Since it's true *for a circle* that the midpoints of parallel chords determine a line that contains the center, then the same is true *for an ellipse*.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Pick the endpoints of the minor axis, and draw circles with diameter equal to the length of the major axis. The intersection points of the two circles are the foci(Even better, the intersection of a circle with the major axis).